# Windows forms control is not showing in screen eventually

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using winforms which is having one panel and inside that panel it is having a groupbox .

In group box it is having two more control of radio button.
In client machine sometime this screen is coming as blank with no radio button. What it is showing only group box title.

I have checked it is happening 2-3 in a day only otherwise it is working fine.

This screen we are calling as a showdialog from parent form.

Below is the smiliar problem reported to microsoft forum 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8bfb02d5-70df-45a0-96ae-7aef4d4d427c/win-form-is-not-loading-properly-with-windows-8?forum=winforms

but not able to find the solution for this.
Please let me know if anyone encounter with similar kind of issue and what is the solution for this.

Sample code for this:

```
  private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.groupBox1 = new Cross.CustomControls.GroupBox();
        this.rb1 = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
        this.rb2 = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
        this.btnOK = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.lblMessage = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.groupBox1.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 

        // groupBox1
        // 
        this.groupBox1.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(208)))), ((int)(((byte)(208)))), ((int)(((byte)(191)))));
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.rb1);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.rb2);
        this.groupBox1.DrawTopOnly = false;
        this.groupBox1.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.System;
        this.groupBox1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 11.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.groupBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(72, 141);
        this.groupBox1.Name = "groupBox1";
        this.groupBox1.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 21, 3, 2);
        this.groupBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(277, 74);
        this.groupBox1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.groupBox1.Text = "DF";
        this.groupBox1.TitleColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
        // 
        // rb1
        // 
        this.rb1.AutoSize = true;
        this.rb1.Checked = true;
        this.rb1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(30, 35);
        this.rb1.Name = "rb1";
        this.rb1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(101, 21);
        this.rb1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.rb1.TabStop = true;
        this.rb1.Text = "rb1";
        this.rb1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.rb1.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.rb1_CheckedChanged);
        // 
        // rb2
        // 
        this.rb2.AutoSize = true;
        this.rb2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(149, 35);
        this.rb2.Name = "rb2";
        this.rb2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(96, 21);
        this.rb2.TabIndex = 1;
        this.rb2.TabStop = true;
        this.rb2.Text = "rb2";
        this.rb2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.rb2.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.rb2_CheckedChanged);
        // 
        // btnOK
        // 
        this.btnOK.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.System;
        this.btnOK.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(274, 221);
        this.btnOK.Name = "btnOK";
        this.btnOK.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 29);
        this.btnOK.TabIndex = 2;
        this.btnOK.Text = "&OK";
        this.btnOK.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnOK_Click);
        // 
        // lblMessage
        // 
        this.lblMessage.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(72, 85);
        this.lblMessage.Name = "lblMessage";
        this.lblMessage.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(337, 42);
        this.lblMessage.TabIndex = 3;

        // 
        // frmDFCardType
        // 
        this.ArchSubTitle = "c";
        this.ArchTitle = "CT";
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(7F, 16F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(421, 273);
        this.Controls.Add(this.lblMessage);
        this.Controls.Add(this.btnOK);
        this.Controls.Add(this.groupBox1);
        this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.Name = "frmDFCardType";
        this.Controls.SetChildIndex(this.PleaseWait, 0);
        this.Controls.SetChildIndex(this.groupBox1, 0);
        this.Controls.SetChildIndex(this.btnOK, 0);
        this.Controls.SetChildIndex(this.lblMessage, 0);
        this.groupBox1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.groupBox1.PerformLayout();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);


    }
```

Comment: Show the full code because this part you pasted makes no sense at all.

Comment: added the designer code !

Comment: Try to remove code with SuspendLayout, ResumeLayout and PerformLayout and see what happens

Comment: Adam , tried with that and no issue occurs. Is anything related to Autoscaledimensions and AutoScaleMode here for windows 10 & 8 , as this issue is occuring in windows 10 and Windows 8 only?

Answer (score 4):

```
    this.groupBox1.DrawTopOnly = false;
    this.groupBox1.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.System;
```

Nobody will be able to repro your problem from the posted snippet, we don't know what the Cross.CustomControls.GroupBox class does.  But these two statements are a half-decent clue towards the underlying issue.

FlatSystem.System has a pretty unusual side-effect on the GroupBox class.  *Normally* the control does all of its own painting, but with System in effect it relies on a built-in native Windows control to get the job done.  A rather weirdo control, it is the "Button" class.  One of the many hacks Microsoft had to use 30 years ago to cram a GUI operating system in 256 kilobytes of RAM.

One thing it does not support at all is any kind of custom painting.  The `DrawTopOnly` property strongly suggests that is what this control is actually doing.  Requires pretty significant hackorama by intercepting the paint messages with a WndProc() method overload.

This can easily go wrong.  One possible scenario is that the painting code itself causes the paint region to get invalidated again.  This has a very unintuitive side-effect, any child controls of the groupbox never get painted.  Like those two radiobuttons.  Pretty hard to diagnose, everything looks entirely normal beyond those child controls just being missing.  One thing you *can* see, the UI thread of your program starts burning 100% core, painting the groupbox or its parent over and over again.  Task Manager can show that.

First thing to do is replace the custom GroupBox with a normal one.  Next thing to do is giving SO users a shot at helping you by posting *all* of the code needed to repro the issue.